# Unable to authorize despite connection string copied from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string

I have a site hosted in Azure. It's a vanilla MVC project but when I try to register a user I'm getting an error as follows.

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'BeepBeep'.

I'm not sure why it's giving me the error. The connection string in the config files looks like this (change credentials, of course).

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
     connectionString="
       Server=tcp:f8goq0bvq7.database.windows.net,1433;
       Database=MyDataBase;
       User ID=BeepBeep@f8goq0bvq7;
       Password=Bzzzz;
       Encrypt=True;
       TrustServerCertificate=False;
       Connection Timeout=30;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I've verified the same credentials with SQL Management Studio and I get logged in. Possibly, the authorization doesn't ask for DB credentials (although the error occurs while trying to register a new user via the default vanilla MVC site). Not sure where to poke it, though.

Any ideas on how to trouble-shoot it?

## Edit

Based on the comments, we've verified that the database is set up to accept calls from Azure Services and that the hole in the firewall spans from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. We also made sure that the credentials were correctly specified in the Azure portal (same result using them as well as the upload config file).

Comment: domain logins can take "email" form, e.g. `user@domain`, so it's possible that you're being rejected for trying to login from an unknown domain, and mssql is simply not regurgitating that domain name.

Comment: @MarcB Fix for that? I recall vaguely that one needed to register the current IP address for the connection **but** I can't register all the possible users that will access the page, can I?

Comment: Are you trying to use the logged in users credentials to authenticate sql connection?

Comment: @Aram Nope. I just uploaded the default, vanilla MVC project and I'm trying to register the user. When I'm kicking *Register* I get this error. The only part I've changed is the connection string because the one already there was pointing to a local database.

Comment: can you paste your connection string?

Comment: @Aram Sure, mate. Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: does it work in SQL Management studio if you don't user the @Servername in user name section?

Comment: @Aram Yes it does. Surprisingly to me, because I know for sure that I couldn't make that happen before (over a year ago). This was a new thing to me. Are you implying that I should that **that** in the connection string? I just did and, sadly, no. It didn't change anything...

Comment: Can you check the Azure portal under Connection string section and see you have the correct password there?

Comment: @Aram It doesn't. It only says *"{your_password_here}"*.

Comment: there you go! you found it, put your password there...

Comment: @Aram I did. See the connection string in the question? The part that says *"{your_password_here}"* is a non-editable text box in the portal...

Comment: edited the answer, when you click on it will give you 2 text boxes and one dropdown. the second textbox is the connection string that you should update...

Comment: So, you mentioned that you were able to connect to the database service via SQL Server Management Studio, using those credentials.  Just because you can connect to the server doesn't necessarily mean that you can access the given **database**.  Can you confirm that, once connected via SQL Server Management Studio you can also run a query against your database?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Excellent remark. I should've been clearer. Yes, I'm confirming that I'm able to access the actual database on the server and I'm able to create tables and do other stuff (the granted role is *db_owner*). I also created a new user (while logged in) and granted owner permissions to them. Verifying that even they could log in and do  stuff, I still got the same error from Azure, though. The tables that are supposed to be created by the authorization facility simply aren't there...

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the connection string?

Can you check if it has {} around your password?

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1-20140927090028;User ID=myid;Password={mypsw};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If yes, remove the {} from around your password...

Or

Can you check the Azure portal under Connection string section and see you have the correct password there
[image]

Or in the new Azure portal it looks like this:

1. Select your website
2. Click Application Settings
3. Go to Connection Strings section and edit the password

[image]

Here is firewall setting in new portal for the SQL Server setting:

[image]

Comment: Connection string is fetched from the Azure portal. The curly braces are removed. Good try, though, so +1. Not resolving my issue though.

Comment: I can't find it. It doesn't look like that on my computer. See the screen in the question? I've updated it again.

Comment: I went to the old portal but I still can't see the exact look of your image. I got however to see the connection string and those too have no password entered. I've rechecked that it's the correct one though...

Comment: This is not funny at all! Why am I specifying web.config if I need to do that again there?! I'm a lazy person...   :)        Well, we might have hit something. I have **no** connection strings there. No nothing, not even a dummy one.

Comment: Well the idea is you can change it in different environments to point to different sql instances from your subscription. but if you dont have anything there, then it should just read the web.config

Comment: Do I also need to set the database to be accessible from Azure services as @stuartsmith mentioned?

Comment: Just rechecked and the error still remains, so I guess it's as you say - the web-config should be effective if there was no connection string defined in the portal... More ideas?

Comment: yes you need to turn on access to Azure Services too, edited the answer with the screen shot for that.

Comment: Where do I do that? Also, I just discovered that when I changed the *BeepBeep* to *Blopp* in my config and *Boink* in the portal, I still get the same error! It's still *BeepBeep* that's reported to fail authorization. What is that?!

Comment: Ah, I had to go under the submenu to get to SQlL Server. Found it. Sadly, it was already turned on and one of the rules spans from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255... Try to access the page yourself and see the error...

Comment: Maybe the user has disappeared when they upgraded the cloud? I try to add a user, pick a role of owner but then it requires me to enter an email. I want to create a user with a user name, like *SomeUser1*, not to invite anybody... Am I way off?

Comment: yo dont need to invite new user, it is sql user that you need, run queries from this page to create new logins: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/

Comment: Darn... This is **exactly** how I created the user... ANd I've checked the groups and password again... It feels a bit like if we're not using the web.config, though. When I changed the user name there to something intentionally different, the error message on the site complained about the old user name failing to authorize, still...

Comment: I've done that. I had one name in the portal, another in the web.config and still, the old one appeared on the site. I don't understand it and I can't even see how to trouble-shoot it... We've put a few hours into this, I learned a lot, but still, the darn thingy doesn't work... I even tested republish and checked if the connection is valid in there. It was!

Comment: you might have it somewhere else in the code other that the config you are looking at.

Comment: Hehe, way before you, mate. I've checked all the files in the project. The string was only in the config and publish files. Weird... I'm unsure if we can make it work tonight - it's getting late now. If you can think of something else, shoot. This will definitely be a bounty question.   :(

Answer (score 1):

In Azure

Did you change your database to be able to be Contacted from Azure Services?

You can find this on the configure tab of the DB Server.

Comment: No, I haven't. Didn't know about it. Where's that exactly? (I'm still getting used to the new L&F of the portal...

Comment: In the old portal click  on the database. Click dashboard, find server on the right hand side, click on the server name, Click Configure in the tabs on the server portal

Comment: Would you mind posting screen of that? I can't find it. Preferably from the new interface style, if possible.

Comment: I can only find it in the old portal  here is a link on how to get to it https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/

Comment: Thank, mate. We've found that setting in the new one, already, after your hint. Sadly, it was already turned on **and** it has the widest range possible allowed...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it did not fix your error. I got burned by this same sort of error a while ago when setting an Azure Mobil service.Please post what the actual solution. When you figure it out this is a stumper.